# How to search keyword without hide irrelevant lines in chrome console?

Tags: google-chrome, search, devtools

Everyone can filter keyword in chrome console, but other lines without the keyword will be hidden. However, the context of log is also important. So, How can I search a keyword in chrome console without hide irrelevant lines?

I have googled it, and I get nothing about it.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What is the broader goal you are trying to achieve by doing this?